# PLS-00402: alias required in SELECT list of cursor to avoid duplicate column names

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written a stored procedure to pull the data from three different table using join but I'm not able get the result.I'm also trying to pass dynamic table but there is error occurred.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure DE_DUP_PRO1 (Dy_File_Name in varchar2) 
   --RETURN NUMBER
AS
       v_hol varchar2(300);

  CURSOR De_DUB_CUR IS
  SELECT S.TRANS_GUID AS OLD_TRANS_GUID,
  H.TRANS_GUID    AS NEW_TRANS_GUID,
  CASE
    WHEN H.TRANS_GUID IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END as TRN_STAT,
        P.INTR_PHARMACY_ID, S.EXTRNL_PHARMACY_ID,  S.PHARMACY_NM,  S.PHARMACY_ADDR,  S.SUPPLIERS_PSCR_DRUG_CD,  S.PSCR_DRUG_IPU_CD,
        'IPU',  S.PSCR_DRUG_DESC,  S.DSPNSD_DRUG_PACK_SIZE,  S.RX_ID,  S.RX_ITEM_SEQ,  S.RX_REPEAT_STATUS,  S.RX_TYP,  S.EXMT_STATUS,
        S.PSCR_QTY,  S.NRSG_HM_IND,  S.RX_DSPNSD_DT,  S.RX_DSPNSD_TM,  S.SUPPLIERS_DSPNSD_DRUG_CD,  S.DSPNSD_DRUG_IPU_CD, 'IPU',
        S.DSPNSD_DRUG_DESC,  S.GENERIC_USE_MARKER,  S.DSPNSD_UNIT_OF_QTY,  S.DSPNSD_QTY, 'EUR',  S.COST_OF_DSPNSD_QTY,  S.VERBOSE_DOSAGE

  FROM (SELECT stg.*, row_number() over ( partition BY key_clmns_hash ORDER BY 1 ) AS RN FROM  T_MCL_30404_20150317_020 stg ) s


  LEFT JOIN ps_pharmacy p ON s.extrnl_pharmacy_id = p.extrnl_pharmacy_id LEFT JOIN ps_rx_hist H ON h.key_clmns_hash = s.key_clmnS_hash
  AND h.rx_dspnsd_dt = s.rx_dspnsd_dt AND s.supplier_pharmacy_cd = h.SUPPLIER_PHARMACY_CD AND s.detl_clmns_hash <> h.detl_clmns_hash WHERE S.RN = 1;

BEGIN


      FOR De_Dub_rec IN  De_DUB_CUR
      LOOP

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( De_Dub_rec.OLD_TRANS_GUID || '|' || De_Dub_rec.NEW_TRANS_GUID || '|' || De_Dub_rec.TRN_STAT || '|' || De_Dub_rec.P.INTR_PHARMACY_ID || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.EXTRNL_PHARMACY_ID
 || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.PHARMACY_NM || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.PHARMACY_ADDR || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.SUPPLIERS_PSCR_DRUG_CD|| '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.PSCR_DRUG_IPU_CD || '|' || 'IPU' 
 || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.PSCR_DRUG_DESC || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.DSPNSD_DRUG_PACK_SIZE || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.RX_ID || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.RX_ITEM_SEQ || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.RX_REPEAT_STATUS 
 || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.RX_TYP || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.EXMT_STATUS || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.PSCR_QTY || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.NRSG_HM_IND || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.RX_DSPNSD_DT 
 || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.RX_DSPNSD_TM || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.SUPPLIERS_DSPNSD_DRUG_CD || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.DSPNSD_DRUG_IPU_CD || '|' || 'IPU' || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.DSPNSD_DRUG_DESC 
 || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.GENERIC_USE_MARKER || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.DSPNSD_UNIT_OF_QTY  || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.DSPNSD_QTY || '|' || 'EUR' || '|' || De_Dub_rec.S.COST_OF_DSPNSD_QTY 
 || '|'|| De_Dub_rec.S.VERBOSE_DOSAGE );

      END LOOP;

--   RETURN 0;

END DE_DUP_PRO1;
/
```

whenever I'm execute stored procedure I get below error

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
7/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
19/96    PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
31/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
31/32    PLS-00364: loop index variable 'DE_DUB_REC' use is invalid

LINE/COL ERROR(Now it is resolved)
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
28/7     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
28/7     PLS-00402: alias required in SELECT list of cursor to avoid
         duplicate column names
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your query is selecting a few literal string values without setting any aliases:

```
select ..., 'IPU', ... , 'IPU', ..., 'EUR', ...
```

In the above case, Oracle will auto-generate ugly aliases that look something like this:

```
select ..., 'IPU' AS "'IPU'", ..., 'IPU' AS "'IPU'", ..., 'EUR' AS "'EUR'", ...
```

So as you can see, you now have 3 very ugly column names that are very awkward to work with, and 2 of them are duplicate, resulting in the error you are getting.

Consider giving them proper distinct aliases to avoid the ambiguity. This is just an example, but you should give a more meaningful alias according to the meaning of the value:

```
select ..., 'IPU' AS some_col_1, ..., 'IPU' AS some_col_2, ..., 'EUR' AS some_col_3, ...
```

---

The funny thing is that you are ***not*** currently using those 3 values when reading the query in your cursor for loop.  When reading/looping  through your cursor, instead of trying to read the 3 values from the cursor, you simply hard-code the values again as you are printing them out.

So in fact, if you really don't care about reading the 3 values from the cursor, just remove them from the query altogether.  Otherwise, replace your hard-coded values from your `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(...)` with the aliases that you set.

So once your query is fixed, instead of:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(... || 'IPU' || ... || 'IPU' || ... || 'EUR' || ...);
```

You should probably use the cursor like this:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(... || De_Dub_rec.some_col_1 || ... || De_Dub_rec.some_col_2 || ... || De_Dub_rec.some_col_3 || ...);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply....now i'm getting below error LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
34/9     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
34/145   PLS-00302: component 'P' must be declared       I need to give every column alias or not

Comment: thanks sstan my problem has been resolved,there one more error I'm getting.

Comment: I would prefer `IPU' AS "IPU"` over `IPU' AS "'IPU'"`

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name @ thanks for your reply this problem has been resolved I'm getting one more error 19/96    PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: It seems like your error keeps changing as you debug through.  If you want help with your latest error, it's probably best if you formulate a new question with all the relevant details.  Your last error is pretty self explanatory. Either one of the tables you are referring to doesn't exist, or you don't have the required permissions to read it. But beyond that, there aren't enough details to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding the below code of line is generating the error due to column ambiguity.

```
SELECT stg.*, row_number() over ( partition BY key_clmns_hash ORDER BY 1
```

Just explicitly mention the column name with aliases in the above line instead of using stg.* and that will solve your problem