# PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'CHR' reference is out of scope

Tags: oracle, plsql

i make a procedure in plsql it return this error anyone know about it i post my code and error snap shot here

[image]

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHR.ATT_INSERT_TEST
IS
   CURSOR ATT
   IS
      SELECT   emp.EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_ID,
         io.CHECKTYPE CHECKTYPE,
         io.MACHINE_NUM MACHINE_NUM,
         io.ATT_ID ATT_ID, 
         io.SWIPE_DATE SWIPE_DATE,
         io.SWIPE_TIME SWIPE_TIME
  FROM   INOUT_LIVE_MACHINE_TEST io, CHR_EMGT_EMPLOYEE emp
 WHERE   emp.EMPLOYEE_CODE = io.EMPLOYEE_CODE
 AND io.ATT_ID NOT IN (SELECT   ATT_ID_REF
                                 FROM   CHR_TA_EMP_SWIPE_IN_OUT
                                WHERE   io.ATT_ID = ATT_ID_REF);
BEGIN
   FOR I IN ATT
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO CHR_TA_EMP_SWIPE_IN_OUT (EMPLOYEE_ID,
                                           SWIPE_DATE,
                                           SWIPE_TIME,
                                           SWIPE_ID,
                                           SWIPE_TYPE,
                                           CREATED_BY,
                                           CREATION_DATE,
                                           CLIENT_IP)
        VALUES   (I.EMPLOYEE_ID,
                  TO_DATE (i.SWIPE_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                  I.SWIPE_TIME,
                  CHR_TA_SWIPE_IN_OUT_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
                  I.CHECKTYPE,
                  I.EMPLOYEE_ID,
                  TO_DATE (i.SWIPE_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                  '192.168.0.71'
                  );
   END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

this is my procedure i make subquery mostly time but this time it return me this kind of error.
i think this error show some issue is regarding alias but i already define alias for each column
i read this artical but my code is still stuck

[PLS-00402: alias required in SELECT list of cursor to avoid duplicate column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027601/pls-00402-alias-required-in-select-list-of-cursor-to-avoid-duplicate-column-nam)

this is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE CHR.CHR_TA_EMP_SWIPE_IN_OUT
(
  EMPLOYEE_ID       NUMBER(10)                  NOT NULL,
  SWIPE_DATE        DATE                        NOT NULL,
  SWIPE_TIME        DATE                        NOT NULL,
  SWIPE_ID          NUMBER(10)                  NOT NULL,
  SWIPE_TYPE        VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  CREATED_BY        NUMBER(10),
  CREATION_DATE     DATE,
  LAST_UPDATED_BY   NUMBER(10),
  LAST_UPDATE_DATE  DATE,
  IS_MANUAL         VARCHAR2(1 BYTE),
  REASON_LKP        NUMBER(10),
  CLIENT_IP         VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  IS_REQUESTED      VARCHAR2(1 CHAR),
  TERMINAL_ID       VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  ATT_ID_REF        NUMBER
)

CREATE TABLE CHR.CHR_EMGT_EMPLOYEE
(
  EMPLOYEE_ID                NUMBER(10)         NOT NULL,
  EMPLOYEE_CODE              VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)  NOT NULL
  )



CREATE TABLE CHR.INOUT_LIVE_MACHINE_TEST 
(
  ATT_ID         NUMBER,
  USERID         NUMBER,
  EMPLOYEE_CODE  NUMBER,
  SENSORID       NUMBER,
  MACHINE_NUM    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  CHECKTIME      VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  CHECKTYPE      VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
)
```

Comment: Can you remove the CHR from the "PROCEDURE CHR.ATT_INSERT_TEST" and try once..

Comment: yes i try but same issue

Comment: Please post table ddl so that i can also check ..Create table statements

Comment: please check tables structure

Comment: first table and third table name is same and  ddl for INOUT_LIVE_MACHINE_TEST  and  CHR_EMGT_EMPLOYEE  is missing

Comment: sorry my typing mistake now see again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure has no mistakes. Only problem is in your table "INOUT_LIVE_MACHINE_TEST". it has missing SWIPE_DATE & SWIPE_TIME columns. See below the working demo.

***Created table with both the columns:***

```
CREATE TABLE INOUT_LIVE_MACHINE_TEST 
(
  ATT_ID         NUMBER,
  USERID         NUMBER,
  EMPLOYEE_CODE  NUMBER,
  SENSORID       NUMBER,
  SWIPE_DATE        DATE                        NOT NULL,
  SWIPE_TIME        DATE                        NOT NULL,
  MACHINE_NUM    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  CHECKTIME      VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  CHECKTYPE      VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
)
```

***Procedure compiled :***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ATT_INSERT_TEST
IS
   CURSOR ATT
   IS
      SELECT   emp.EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE_ID,
         io.CHECKTYPE CHECKTYPE,
         io.MACHINE_NUM MACHINE_NUM,
         io.ATT_ID ATT_ID, 
         io.SWIPE_DATE SWIPE_DATE,
         io.SWIPE_TIME SWIPE_TIME
  FROM   INOUT_LIVE_MACHINE_TEST io, CHR_EMGT_EMPLOYEE emp
 WHERE   emp.EMPLOYEE_CODE = io.EMPLOYEE_CODE
 AND io.ATT_ID NOT IN (SELECT   ATT_ID_REF
                                 FROM   CHR_TA_EMP_SWIPE_IN_OUT
                                WHERE   io.ATT_ID = ATT_ID_REF);
BEGIN
   FOR I IN ATT
   LOOP
      INSERT INTO CHR_TA_EMP_SWIPE_IN_OUT (EMPLOYEE_ID,
                                           SWIPE_DATE,
                                           SWIPE_TIME,
                                           SWIPE_ID,
                                           SWIPE_TYPE,
                                           CREATED_BY,
                                           CREATION_DATE,
                                           CLIENT_IP)
        VALUES   (I.EMPLOYEE_ID,
                  TO_DATE (i.SWIPE_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                  I.SWIPE_TIME,
                  CHR_TA_SWIPE_IN_OUT_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
                  I.CHECKTYPE,
                  I.EMPLOYEE_ID,
                  TO_DATE (i.SWIPE_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                  '192.168.0.71'
                  );
   END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: dear issue still same ,i think probability this error due to procedure privileges ?

Comment: I hope you removed CHR as well and ran my piece of code..With CHR in your procedure name, it tried to look for that user and if not exist it throws error. It cannot be priv issue coz its showing out of scope.